# Presto JDBC Connection Pool Creation ERROR "Disabling auto-commit mode not supported"

Tags: java, spring-jdbc, hikaricp, presto

I am trying to use Spring-JDBC to connect to Presto and I am using Hikari CP for datasource.
Here is my configuration:

```
@Bean
public DataSource myDataSource() {
    HikariDataSource hikariDataSource = new HikariDataSource();
    hikariDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoDriver");
    hikariDataSource.setJdbcUrl("xxxxxxx");
    hikariDataSource.setMaximumPoolSize(10);
    hikariDataSource.setMinimumIdle(5);
    hikariDataSource.setIdleTimeout(10000);
    hikariDataSource.setConnectionTimeout(60000);
    hikariDataSource.setUsername("xxxx");
    hikariDataSource.setPassword("xxxx");
    hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);

    return hikariDataSource;
}
```

While autowiring the datasource in my service class, I am getting this error:

```
java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Disabling auto-commit mode not supported
at com.facebook.presto.jdbc.PrestoConnection.setAutoCommit(PrestoConnection.java:126) ~[presto-jdbc-0.163.jar:0.163]
```

Dependencies: for Springboot base 1.5.10.RELEASE

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.facebook.presto</groupId>
        <artifactId>presto-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>0.163</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

You are disabling auto commit mode in line:

```
hikariDataSource.setAutoCommit(false);
```

while your Presto driver is not supporting this operation and will throw an exception. Remove the the `setAutoCommit(false)` from your `@Bean`. This is discussed in an [open issue #3592](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/issues/3592).

Another option would be to update the driver to newer version as on master the auto commit is [already handled in PrestoConnection](https://github.com/prestodb/presto/blob/master/presto-jdbc/src/main/java/com/facebook/presto/jdbc/PrestoConnection.java#L137). Latest version is 0.197.

Answer (score 1):

Faced this issue recently and stumbled upon [this](https://github.com/tpolecat/doobie/issues/339) discussion in github.
I tried hikari CP and commons dbcp both and tried both autoCommit (true) and (false) but nothing seemed to work.

Somehow in spring-jdbc, I see multiple calls happening to PrestoConnection class where for once boolean autoCommit comes as false resulting in this error.
Solution

1) Override the beans created to make sure you pass valid arguments

2) Upgrade to latest 0.197 presto-jdbc, it worked for me (as mentioned in answer by Karol)